What are the right metrics to validate the performance of a custom clustering model with three possible outcomes?
I have developed a custom clustering model on top of MiniBatchKmeans, that has three possible outcomes for each data point:

Assign the point to the correct cluster.
Assign the point to the wrong cluster.
Create a new cluster.

I'm looking for appropriate metrics to evaluate the performance of this model. I am aware of common clustering evaluation metrics like Adjusted Rand Index (ARI), Silhouette Score, and Davies-Bouldin Index, but I am not sure how they apply to the unique outcomes of my model.
Specifically, I want to understand how to:

Measure the accuracy of assigning points to the correct clusters.
Penalize the creation of unnecessary new clusters.
Account for points that are assigned to the wrong clusters.

Can anyone recommend metrics or a combination of metrics that would best validate the performance of my custom clustering model? Additionally, if there are any best practices or examples of handling such scenarios, I would appreciate the insights.
Thank you!
While these metrics (Adjusted Rand Index (ARI), Silhouette Score, Davies-Bouldin Index) provide some insights, they don't fully capture the three specific outcomes of my model. I expected to find a metric or a combination of metrics that would:

Clearly indicate when points are correctly clustered.
Penalize unnecessary creation of new clusters.
Account for misassigned points.

